# Is there any GPU that has 100+ Mh/s?

Tags: ethereum-classic, hardware

After I browsed http://www.mininghwcomparison.com, I found some GPU that had a 100+ hashrate, to 250Mh/s. I checked many other sites, and I didn't see any GPU that goes over 50MH/s, so is this site legit ? Is there any hardware that has a 100+ hashrate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all user-submitted values and also non-Ethash-based algorithms. For the most part, the users submitting 100 MH/s+ hash rates have indicated these are for multi-GPU systems. For example, someone has submitted this:

- ASUS 2х7990  1000    1500    win 8.1 pro 16.1    Ethereum    95Mh/s

The HD 7990 is, itself, two GPUs rolled into one. And this user has indicated that the 95MH/s is achieved with two of them. That means that each processor is cranking out a bit under 24MH/s -- more in line with what you're probably expecting.

Answer (score 1):

https://gpulister.com/gpu/66/amd-r7-370-equihash-hashrate

Yes here is more gpu listed with 100+ hashrate. also you can search more gpu with  hash rate their configuration such as Core clock, Memory Clock, Power consumption,Driver Version,Operating System for specific algorithm.